# why does tomcat classloader break up parent delegation

Tags: tomcat, classloader

as you know,  parent delegation  is the default principle when class loading. 
but tomcat break it . why ?

in my opinion, it is unnecessary. WebAppClassLoader  overriding  the findClass to load class at the web app  web-inf/classes ,web-inf/lib is enough.

do you agree me with me  ? why?

Comment: by the way every web app at tomcat have unique WebAppClassLoader instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [JavaDoc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.html) of `WeAppClassLoader` says:

> **By default, this class loader follows the delegation model required by the specification**. The system class loader will be queried first, then the local repositories, and only then delegation to the parent class loader will occur. This allows the web application to override any shared class except the classes from J2SE. Special handling is provided from the JAXP XML parser interfaces, the JNDI interfaces, and the classes from the servlet API, which are never loaded from the webapp repositories. The delegate property allows an application to modify this behavior to move the parent class loader ahead of the local repositories.

(emphasis mine)